# Validate Velocity Template

Tags: java, xml, velocity

I'm generating XML files with Apache Velocity, generally using #if blocks, like so:

```
<tag>
    <subtag>content</subtag>
    #if(a)
    <subtag attribute="value">content_a</subtag>
    #end
</tag>
```

The resulting XML is then validated with an XSD. Is it possible to do a similar validation in Velocity? I couldn't find anything unfortunately.

If not, is there any XML-like language that does something similar like Velocity?

Any input would be great, thanks!

Comment: If you're generating XML, I'd *consider* XSLT.

Comment: Following up on XSLT, you can feed it a "context" from Java objects using ```JAXBSource```.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in velocity template validation, you'd better go to the post [Apache Velocity: Is there a standard way of verifying the correctness of a template from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910857/apache-velocity-is-there-a-standard-way-of-verifying-the-correctness-of-a-templ) as suggested by Markus.

If you are looking for a tool similar to Velocity that accepts an XML syntax, you may have a look to [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org).